# Paste code containing tabs into scala repl

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I am using

```
:paste
```

before copying in a scala code snippet that apparently contains tabs.  But even so the following occurs:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

type Moves = Seq[Board]
val EmptyMoves = Seq[Board]()

def allMoves() = {
Display all 413 possibilities? (y or n)
e = (‘x’,’o’).map{ case xo =>
Display all 413 possibilities? (y or n)
dex
Display all 413 possibilities? (y or n)
t, ix % 3) }
```

So then is there **any** way to be able to put code with tabs into the repl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need this [rather trivial fix](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5240) to the REPL.

Alternatively, you can implement the fix and supply `-Dscala.repl.reader=my.Reader`.

The other answer suggests finding ways to hijack the reader:

```
scala> :power
Power mode enabled. :phase is at typer.
import scala.tools.nsc._, intp.global._, definitions._
Try :help or completions for vals._ and power._

scala> import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter._, java.io._
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter._
import java.io._

scala> def f(code: String) = repl.savingReader {
     | repl.in = new SimpleReader(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(code)), new PrintWriter(scala.Console.out), false)
     | repl.loop() }
f: (code: String)$r.repl.LineResults.LineResult

scala> f("val x = 42. toInt")    // embedded tab
x: Int = 42
res5: $r.repl.LineResults.LineResult = EOF
```

Or foregoing editing:

```
$ scala -Xnojline
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> 

scala> val x = 42.  toInt
x: Int = 42
```

Or foregoing completion:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val x = 42.             // 42 tab toInt
!=   /    >=          ceil          getClass        isPosInfinity   isWhole     shortValue       toDegrees     toOctalString   underlying   
%    <    >>          compare       intValue        isValidByte     longValue   signum           toDouble      toRadians       until        
&    <<   >>>         compareTo     isInfinite      isValidChar     max         to               toFloat       toShort         |            
*    <=   ^           doubleValue   isInfinity      isValidInt      min         toBinaryString   toHexString   unary_+                      
+    ==   abs         floatValue    isNaN           isValidLong     round       toByte           toInt         unary_-                      
-    >    byteValue   floor         isNegInfinity   isValidShort    self        toChar           toLong        unary_~                      

scala> val x = 42.toInt
x: Int = 42

scala> :power
Power mode enabled. :phase is at typer.
import scala.tools.nsc._, intp.global._, definitions._
Try :help or completions for vals._ and power._

scala> import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter._
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter._

scala> repl.in = new jline.InteractiveReader(() => NoCompletion)
repl.in: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.InteractiveReader = scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.InteractiveReader@10660795

scala> val x = 42.toInt
x: Int = 42
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not expect to actually receive an answer on this question .. and got one .. from *the*  @som-snytt

Comment: btw why `*scala*.tools.nsc.interpreter._`  when `import tools.nsc.interpreter._` were sufficient?  Is it a style thing?

Comment: It's for hygiene; I'm often in a dir with a subdir `util` which is taken as a package. `tools` is also a common name, but here I did it for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can paste your code in a file and then do the following command in your REPL:

```
 scala> :load YourFile.scala
```

***NB***: the file should not have package declarations or else the loading will fail.

Comment: That's a handy workaround. It works because completion isn't enabled when reading from a file.

Comment: It is as workaround as using scalac instead of interpreter. The completion must be disabled with `:paste` option as well. Otherwise, paste mode makes no sense at all.